# Using Android Mini Pc for Debugging

Tags: android, debugging

I have a android mini pc  http://www.timingpower.com/android-mini-pc-rk3188
I want to debug my eclipse code. Is it possible? Which cable should ı use to connect my laptop  and do ı need to do something more?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a very similar device. Like your's mine had a full sized usb port (host) and a micro usb port (OTG). Apparently some builds provide adb over the micro usb port. this was not the case with mine.

Instead I used the builtin wifi to provide adb over tcp.
You can either search the playstore for "adb wifi" or do it manually see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)